Rolling sums of last 3 days and 1 days in single query
I have a table with data for last 6 days:

I need 3 new columns for device: (1) the sum of October 3rd to 5th, regardless of the day (2) a rolling sum for the dates October 3rd to 5th using their immediate preceding day, (3) a rolling sum for the dates October 3rd to 5th using their last 3 preceding days.

What I've tried:
SELECT 
   day, country, device,
   SUM(num_visits) OVER (partition by device ORDER BY day ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS device_visits,
   SUM(num_visits) OVER (partition by device ORDER BY day ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS device_visits_1day,
   SUM(num_visits) OVER (partition by device ORDER BY day ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS device_visits_3days
FROM tbl

However in my result the only 'day' columns I get is the earlier dates (2024-09-30,2024-10-01, 2024-10-02) instead of (2024-10-03, 2024-10-04, 2024-10-05)
Also I'm unable to fulfill (1) where the sum is the same regardless of the day.

Just a question, shouldn't you use ORDER BY day DESC since you would otherwise always start with the oldest entry in your table if you sort ascending?

You could get the start - end date, previous day num_visits and sum of num_visits for previous 3 days in an inner query and then in the outer query get the sum for period of last three days (filtered by Where clause):
Sample data



DAY
COUNTRY
DEVICE
NUM_VISITS




30-SEP-24
USA
mobile
50


01-OCT-24
USA
mobile
100


02-OCT-24
USA
mobile
150


03-OCT-24
USA
mobile
200


04-OCT-24
USA
mobile
100


05-OCT-24
USA
mobile
100



--      S Q L : 
Select     day, country, device,
           Sum(num_visits) Over(Partition By device) as device_visits, 
           device_visits_1day, device_visits_3day
From    ( Select  day, country, device, num_visits,
                  Max(day) Over(Partition By device) - 2 as device_start_day,
                  Max(day) Over(Partition By device) as device_end_day,
                  Lag(num_visits) Over(Partition By device Order By day) as device_visits_1day, 
                  Sum(num_visits) Over(Partition By device Order By day
                                       Rows Between 3 Preceding And 1 Preceding) as device_visits_3day
          From tbl
        ) 
Where     day Between device_start_day And device_end_day
Order By device, day;

Result:



DAY
COUNTRY
DEVICE
DEVICE_VISITS
DEVICE_VISITS_1DAY
DEVICE_VISITS_3DAY




03-OCT-24
USA
mobile
400
150
300


04-OCT-24
USA
mobile
400
200
450


05-OCT-24
USA
mobile
400
100
450



Note: Tested with Oracle SQL, but uses standard ANSI syntax, so it should work with presto too. Might need adjustment for device_start_day column calculation as device_end_day - 2 days, though.
fiddle
